# Example of bigmemory and friends with file backing

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I am interested in exploring how R can handle data out-of-memory. I've found the `bigmemory` package and friends (`bigtabulate` and `biganalytics`), but was hoping that someone could point me to a worked out example that uses file backing with these packages. Any other out-of-memory tips would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Charlie, just email [Mike](http://sites.google.com/site/kaneplusplus/) and [Jay](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~jay/), they have a number of examples working around the ASA 'flights' database example from a year or two ago.

*Edit:* In fact, the [Documentation tab](http://sites.google.com/site/bigmemoryorg/research/documentation) has what I had in mind; the scripts are also on the site.

Comment: Chill: they are the authors of the project in question. OP knows. Moreover, I provided a *link* to the project site which has *further links* for Jay and Mike. Did you bother to check?

Comment: That's great, Dirk. I hadn't seen their website, only the CRAN materials. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at "[CRAN Task View: High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)". There is a chapter "Large memory and out-of-memory data" where severel solutions are mentioned. For example package `ff`.

Comment: I had heard of `ff`, but I didn't realize that it was an on-disk solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Any other out-of-memory tips would also be appreciated.*

I frequently work with large datasets. Even though my code has been optimized, I still launch Amazon EC2 instances from time to time because it gives me access to far more resources than on my desk. For example, an instance with 26 ECUs, 8 cores, and 68 gigs of RAM only costs about a $0.80-1.00 per hour (spot instance pricing).

If that seems reasonable, you can launch a public machine image that already has R and do this job in no time.

Comment: I've heard about EC2, but I didn't realize that it was so inexpensive. Thanks!